# P(Z+) is uncountable (Power set of Positive Integers)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have been trying to prove that the Power set of Positive Integers is uncountable using :

Is $i$ an element of the $i$-th subset

But I can not seem to prove it.

Comment: My answer at the duplicate should be enough, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

Given any set $X$, you can prove that no function $f : X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ is surjective. To prove this this, take any such function $f$ and let $B_f = \{ a \in X \mid a \not \in f(a) \} \in \mathcal{P}(X)$; it follows that $B_f \ne f(x)$ for any $x \in X$. This result is known as [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

A corollary of this is that no function $\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is surjective. Can you see where to take it from here?

Comment: So since no function $\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is surjective, there are some elements in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ that are missed and therefor it is uncountable?

Comment: @Rick: You need to connect this fact with the definition of 'countable' that you're working with. Usually, what it means for a set $X$ to be countable is that there is a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to X$, or equivalently a bijection $\mathbb{Z}^+ \to X$. If no function $\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is surjective, why can $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ not be countable?

Comment: So since no function can't be surjective, it can not be countable as to be countable, the function must have a bijection, this contradicts.

Comment: @Rick: Pretty much. It's not that 'the function must be a bijection', but rather that '*some* function must be a bijection'; what you prove is that *no* function is a bijection.